# Variadic Arguments Overflow on Embedded Target

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I am writing a library for interfacing with the HD44780U LCD driver on a TM4C123GH6PM.

I have the following function

```c
void lcd_printf(LCD *lcd, const char *format, ...) {
    char str[81];
    int length;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    length = vsnprintf(str, sizeof(str), format, args);
    va_end(args);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (str[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        lcd_putc(lcd, str[i]);
    }
}
```

which, when run as follows

```c
int main() {
    // omitted init code
    lcd_printf(&lcd, "%i", 1);
}
```

causes an hardware fault, I believe due to a buffer overflow. The error is somewhat intermittent, the same line is used in various places in the code and only some cause errors. If `%i` is not used and instead a plain string is printed, no error occurs. Unfortunately, the more robust `vsnprintf_s` is not available with my toolchain.

If I write out the equivalent code with `snprintf` in the same location, like so

```c
int main() {
    // omitted init code
    char str[81];
    int length;
    length = snprintf(str, 81, "%i", 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (str[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        lcd_putc(lcd, str[i]);
    }
}
```

Then the code runs without any problems.

What errors have I made in `lcd_printf` which invite this overflow?

Comment: The `if (str[i] == '\0')` test is not necessary; the outer loop will stop prior to the NUL terminating byte.

Comment: Yeah I know, just added it in frustration in an attempt to fix this error really.

Comment: How does the hardware fault manifest itself?

Comment: @SteveFriedl Not sure I understand your first comment.  From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/vsnprintf) the `vsnprintf` `"return value is the number of characters (excluding the terminating null byte) which would have been written to the final string if enough space had been available. Thus, a return value of size or more means that the output was truncated"`.  So `length` can be much greater than the size of the buffer passed.

Comment: *the more robust `vsnprintf_s` ...*  [Yeah, no it's not](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#impementations):  "Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs. However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1. ...  As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."  Read that whole document before believing `*_s()` is "more secure" or "more robust".  And either way, it's *de facto* non-portable vendor lock-in.

Comment: @SteveFriedl one of the structures relating to the LCD's pins gets overwritten and it goes into the hardware error routine during `lcd_putc`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle sorry, it wasn't even available in the first place for this target so I didn't research the differences much. I just saw it supposedly had extra error protection added that in the question to pre-empt anybody suggesting it.

Comment: @G.M. *So `length` can be much greater than the size of the buffer passed.* Indeed - that's a potentially deadly bug in the posted code that could explain the problem.  But given `lcd_printf(&lcd, "%i", 1);`, I don't see how an `int` variable can cause an overwrite of an 81-`char` buffer.  Is the currently-posted, post-edit code not a complete and accurate representation of the usage of `lcd_printf()`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Note that the code originally posted was robust in that it had a NUL terminator check in the loop rather than relying on `length` -- and that check has been reinstated as I write this :-)  I agree, however, that the usage of `lcd_printf` shown really shouldn't pose any overflow issues.

Comment: @AndrewHenle As far as I can tell, yes. I am using this very line, with the `1` to avoid any chance of an uninitialised variable. If I remove the line, or replace it with something with no format specifiers e.g. `lcd_printf(&lcd, "test");`, then no error occurs.

Comment: Are you sure the behaviour of `lcd_printf` is the problem rather than just a symptom?  Your previous comment: `"one of the structures relating to the LCD's pins gets overwritten..."` suggests to me that there might be undefined behaviour elsewhere.

Comment: Does your code has proper `#include`s? Do you receive any compiler warnings? Have you exnable all compiler warnings?

Comment: In your working example that uses `snprintf`, you use `lcd`. In your original example, you are passing `&lcd` to `lcd_printf`. If `lcd` [not shown] is defined in the same way in both cases, I think you want to change: `lcd_printf(&lcd, "%i", 1);` into `lcd_printf(lcd, "%i", 1);`. Also, if you're using `gcc`, you could do: `void __attribute__((__format__(__printf__(2,3))) lcd_printf(LCD *lcd, const char *format, ...)` (and compile with `-Wall`) for extra checking.

Comment: @G.M. yeah I'm leaning towards this being the case, however I have scoured the entire code. Also the fact that `lcd_printf(lcd, "1");` behaves differently to `lcd_printf(lcd, "%i", 1);` makes me think it's something to do with the variadic arguments.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, `stdio` & `stdarg` are both included and everything up to `-Wpedantic` produces no warnings.

Comment: @CraigEstey Good catch, I just put that example in hastily for reference. I'm not using GCC and see above re. warnings.

Comment: Then one step at a time, does `snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%i", va_arg(args, int))` work correctly from the function? Does the debugger show that `str` is properly filled? Do you know which line exactly causes hardware overflow? Can you put `lcd_print(??) sleep(1)` after every line, and get which line exactly causes the fault, and confirm it's `vsnprintf`?

Comment: You clearly have not provided all the code, so the error could well be elsewhere, and this is simply the observable point of failure. `vsnprint` likely has significant stack requirement, and on a part with just 32K RAM you likely have a small unitial default stack.  Are you sure that this is not a stack overflow?  How large is your stack?  What are you using if not gcc?  That information may be useful since it may have facilities your analysing stack usage for example (Keil ARM MDK for example can do that).

Comment: See also.https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/arm-based-microcontrollers-group/arm-based-microcontrollers/f/arm-based-microcontrollers-forum/1065741/tm4c123gh6pm-sprintf-and-stack-size. on minimal stack alternatives to the standard library formatted i/o if you are using TivaWare.  Since it is likely to be relevant, you should mention your toolchain in the question itself.  My bet is that your stack is just too small.

Comment: @Clifford On the money there, thanks a lot. I am using Keil MDK. I had 512 bytes of stack space and µVision reported a maximum usage of 412 bytes with the microlib, however upping the stack size to 1024 bytes fixed the issue.

Comment: The stack analysis providing the usage for `main()` will not account for interrupts or calls through function pointers or usage prior to `main()` in the runtime start-up/initialisation.  So you should always add some headroom.  For weird inexplicable behaviour, consider the stack size first - especially if it occurs after calling third-party code with undocumented stack usage requirement.

Comment: There is no such thing as a robust printf. Ideally get rid of it and roll out your own, efficient function without the format string madness and non-existent type safety. stdio.h is good for exactly 2 things: for bugs and for bloating up your program needlessly.